# Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Tags: swift

I have the following model:

```
class Word: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var definitions: NSSet
}
```

Then, in one of my view controllers, I have the following property:

```
var word: Word?
```

However, if I try to do this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
     return self.word?.definitions.count
}
```

I get an error:

> Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!'
>   or '?'?

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html), the value of an optional chaining call is also optional, so `.count` should return an optional Int. So I tried unwrapping it:

```
return self.word?.definitions.count!
```

But that still results in the same error. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: I'd fix that with something like `return self.word?.definitions.count ?? 0`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is the order of operations. The cleanest way to do this would be to stop optional chaining (if you really don't want to handle the nil case).

```
return self.word!.definitions.count
```

But I recommend doing this for safety:

```
if let actualWord = self.word {
   return actualWord.definitions.count
}
else {
   return 0
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
return self.word ? self.word!.definitions.count : 0
```

Otherwise, you might as well declare `word` as an implicitly unwrapped optional and not have to worry about it:

```
var word: Word!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.word.definitions.count
}
```

Comment: Well I can't declare it as an implicitly unwrapped optional since the word can be nil when the view first loads and the table reloads. So I think I have to do your second suggestion. Is there really no other way? What was a 1 liner in Objective-C is now 6 lines with Swift :(